# wiredep for bower not injecting files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, wiredep

I have the following directory structure:

```
bower_components
node_modules
src
index.html
bower.json
package.json
gulpfile.js
.gitignore
```

I have a gulp task to inject the bower dependencies as follows :

```
gulp.task('bower-inject', function () {
    gulp.src('./index.html')
        .pipe(wiredep())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

**index.html**

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="src/assets/images/favicon.ico">
        <title>ABC</title>

        <!-- bower:css -->
        <!-- endbower -->

        <!-- inject:css -->
        <!-- this is done with gulp inject which works as expected -->
        <!-- endinject -->
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppController as appVm">

        <div ui-view></div>

        <!-- bower:js -->
        <!-- endbower -->

        <!-- inject:js -->
        <!-- done via gulp-inject and works as expected -->
        <!-- endinject -->
    </body>
```

**bower.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4",
    "modernizr": "~2.8.3",
    "font-awesome": "~4.3.0"
  }
```

This is what I see when I run the task :

`[00:24:50] Starting 'bower-inject'...
[00:24:50] Finished 'bower-inject' after 14 ms`

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: You sure your `index.html` file still looks like that after overwriting it? Also, you should probably use `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`; wiredep by default does not include `devDependencies`

Comment: yes thats the end product once I run my gulp task. I just set some watchers as well to reload. I tried with both dependencies and devDependencies and got the same result irrespective

Comment: `devDependencies` are more for things like `angular-mocks`, libraries you might use during a build (unit tests, etc) and not necessarily in the normal running of the app

Comment: Have you run `bower install`?

Comment: Yes, when I switched between dependencies and devDependencies, I removed the bower_components folder and ran `bower install` again

Comment: You should also `return gulp.src(...` in your task

Comment: tried, no luck. when I change the destination from `./` to `./src` I am able to see the bower_dependencies being injected, but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('./index.html');

    var sources = gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.css'], {read: false});

    return target
        .pipe(wiredep({
            devDependencies: true
        }))
        .pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: Chances are you had two tasks reading and writing to the same file simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Wiredep will inject script tags when you install your packages as dependencies, not dev-dependencies.
So runing `bower install --save angular angular-bootstrap angular-ui-router bootstrap modernizr font-awesome` and then running your `gulp build` should do it.

**Note**: some packages need overrides configuration on `bower.json`. [Check here](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides) for information on bower overrides if you need.